# How does comma operator behaves with statements?

Tags: c, comma-operator

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main()
{
   int i,printf("Hello");
}
```

when i compiled this code , compiler raised an error:

> error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before string constant
>
> 5 |    int i,printf("Hello");

Can someone tell me what's going wrong??
how does comma operator behave with statements?

Comment: `int i` isn't a statement; it is a declaration (and definition).  You can't use the comma operator between a declaration and a statement; only between statements (more accurately, between expressions).

Answer (score 2):

When we declare multiple variable of same type then we use (,) in between. E.g: int a,b,c;
Here your code mean you have declared prinf function as a integer variable; which is an error. You should put int i; printf("Hello");